# MDX return caption as value

Tags: excel, mdx

I got a following MDX query:

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    [Measures].[Closed Events] ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    Filter
    (
      {
          [Date].[Year].&[2017]*
          ([Date].[Week Number].&[36] : [Date].[Week Number].&[52])*
          [Visited Contact].[Contact SF Id].Children*
          [Assignee].[Role Name].&[PL - Sales Rep HCP]
      }
     ,
      [Measures].[Closed Events] > 0
    ) ON ROWS
FROM [Visit Analysis];
```

How could I influence set within the filter so that I have both year and week number represented as numbers in excel (data table) and not strings?

Answer (score 1):

What about measures?

```
With
Member [Measures].[Year] as
Cint([Date].[Year].CurrentMember.Name)

Member [Measures].[Weak] as
Cint([Date].[Week Number].CurrentMember.Name)

SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {[Measures].[Closed Events],[Measure].[Year],[Measure].[Weak]} ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    Filter
    (
      {
          [Date].[Year].&[2017]*
          ([Date].[Week Number].&[36] : [Date].[Week Number].&[52])*
          [Visited Contact].[Contact SF Id].Children*
          [Assignee].[Role Name].&[PL - Sales Rep HCP]
      }
     ,
      [Measures].[Closed Events] > 0
    ) ON ROWS
FROM [Visit Analysis];
```

Comment: I needed to update Measure into Measures as "Query (2, 1) The dimension '[Measure]' was not found in the cube when the string, [Measure].[Year], was parsed."; but then with Measures I get "The following system error occurred:  Type mismatch." which is strange as those fields are numeric by all means...